# How to use different SweetAlert when function returns bool?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sweetalert2

I'm trying to set up a contact page for a website, and I'd like to add a success sweetalert pop-up when the email is sent (on the same page), and an error alert when any of the fields are left empty, but even when the function (that evaluates if the fields are filled) returns false (left an empty field) it keeps showing the success alert. Currently the website's contact page works well by it's `contact.html` file and a separate `mail.php` file that holds and sends the data while showing the sweetalert success message when sent on the php page which redirects back to the html page. But I would like to be able to show the sweetalert on the same (`contact.php`) page while making the specified alert show depending on which bool value the function will return. Here you can find the [php Contact Page](http://cavenpi.000webhostapp.com/contacto.php) to test the result.

**PHP:**

```
<?php 
global $name;
global $email; 
global $message;
global $subject;
?>

<?php 

    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
        $message = $_POST['message'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['subject'])) {
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    }

    $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
    $recipient = "legonutts@gmail.com";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

?>
```

**HTML:**

```html5
<html>
<body>
    <main>
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <form onsubmit="checkvalidation();" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>
                            <strong>Name</strong>
                        </label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-block" type="submit" value="Send" onclick="return check();">
                            Send
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```js
function checkvalidation(){

        function SweetAlertSuccess(){
            Swal.fire(
                '¡Mensaje enviado!',
                '¡Gracias por contactarnos!',
                'success'
            )
        }

        function SweetAlertError(){
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: '¡Faltan llenar algunos campos!',
                text: 'Los campos requeridos serán remarcados.'
            })
        }

        if ( check() ){
            SweetAlertSuccess();
        }
        else{
            SweetAlertError();
        }

    }

    function check(){

        var name = document.getElementById("name");
        var subject = document.getElementById("subject");
        var email = document.getElementById("email");
        var message = document.getElementById("message");

        var regx = /^([a-z 0-9\.-_]+)@([a-z 0-9-_]+).([a-z]{2,8})(.[a-z]{2,8})?$/;
        if (regx.test())
        {
            email.style.border = "solid 3px #f03535";
            document.getElementById("lblemail2").style.display = "table-row";
            document.getElementById("bremail2").style.display = "table-row";
        }


        if (name.value.trim() == "" && subject.value.trim() == "" && email.value.trim() == "" && message.value.trim() == "" )
        {

            name.style.border = "solid 3px #f03535";
            subject.style.border = "solid 3px #f03535";
            email.style.border = "solid 3px #f03535";
            message.style.border = "solid 3px #f03535";
            document.getElementById("lblname").style.display = "table-row";
            document.getElementById("lblsubject").style.display = "table-row";
            document.getElementById("lblemail").style.display = "table-row";
            document.getElementById("lblmessage").style.display = "table-row";
            document.getElementById("brname").style.display = "table-row";
            document.getElementById("brsubject").style.display = "table-row";
            document.getElementById("bremail").style.display = "table-row";
            document.getElementById("brmessage").style.display = "table-row";
            return false;

        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

I expect the Pop-up alert to be an Error Alert when the Function check() returns false, but a Success alert is shown (which should only happen when it returns true)

**UPDATE:**

I'm also trying to make the contact page not refresh before the sweetalert finishes to pop up and only refresh (when the message is sent) after the user clicks the OK button on the alert (as shown in the example of this [html Contact page](http://cavenpi.000webhostapp.com/contacto.html) that is a `.html` and a separate `.php` file working together) which code is the following:

```
<?php 
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
    $recipient = "legonutts@gmail.com";
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

?>

<body onpageshow="SweetAlertSuccess()">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
<script src="sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill"></script>
<script src="sweetalert2.min.js"></script>

<script>

    function SweetAlertSuccess(){
        Swal.fire({
            title: '¡Mensaje enviado!',
            text: "¡Gracias por contactarnos!",
            icon: 'success',
            showCancelButton: false,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'OK'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                location.href="contacto.html";
            }
        })
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that your function is actually returning `true`? You don't seem to be stopping the `POST` from occurring in your script regardless.

Comment: Yes, (I didn't post the whole explicit code including the css but) when the function returns `false`, every field that was left empty changes the input's border to red plus a label that is hidden by default indicating the missing field, and the email is not sent to my recipient. But when it returns `true`, it effectively sends the email, but the success alert is shown either `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Give me feedback if I read your check function wrong but I guess you want it to alert error either if the regex mail check or the is empty check fails?

```
function check(){

        var name = document.getElementById("name");
        var subject = document.getElementById("subject");
        var email = document.getElementById("email");
        var message = document.getElementById("message");

        var isValid = true;

        var regx = /^([a-z 0-9\.-_]+)@([a-z 0-9-_]+).([a-z]{2,8})(.[a-z]{2,8})?$/;
        // if regex test fails, email is not valid
        if (!regx.test(email.value))
        {
            email.style.border = "solid 3px #f03535";
            document.getElementById("lblemail2").style.display = "table-row";
            document.getElementById("bremail2").style.display = "table-row";
            isValid = false;
        }

        // if name subject or message is empty, its not valid
        if (name.value.trim() == "" && subject.value.trim() == "" && email.value.trim() == "" && message.value.trim() == "" )
        {

            name.style.border = "solid 3px #f03535";
            subject.style.border = "solid 3px #f03535";
            email.style.border = "solid 3px #f03535";
            message.style.border = "solid 3px #f03535";
            document.getElementById("lblname").style.display = "table-row";
            document.getElementById("lblsubject").style.display = "table-row";
            document.getElementById("lblemail").style.display = "table-row";
            document.getElementById("lblmessage").style.display = "table-row";
            document.getElementById("brname").style.display = "table-row";
            document.getElementById("brsubject").style.display = "table-row";
            document.getElementById("bremail").style.display = "table-row";
            document.getElementById("brmessage").style.display = "table-row";
            isValid = false;
        }

        return isValid;

}
```

To stop the submit from happening in case of error your `onSubmit` has to return `false`.

```
async function checkvalidation(submitEvent){
        // this prevents the form from submitting
        submitEvent.preventDefault();

        async function SweetAlertSuccess(){
            return Swal.fire(
                '¡Mensaje enviado!',
                '¡Gracias por contactarnos!',
                'success'
            )
        }

        function SweetAlertError(){
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: '¡Faltan llenar algunos campos!',
                text: 'Los campos requeridos serán remarcados.'
            })
        }

        if ( check() ){
            await SweetAlertSuccess();
            // should only submit after 3 seconds of showing success
            setTimeout(function(){ 
              // give your form the id myForm for this to work
              document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
            }, 3000);

        }
        else{
            SweetAlertError();
        }

}
```

Comment: Hello, Andre! The function does work at least to stop the submit when the Onsubmit returns false (and it does not show the success alert as expected), but it still does not show the sweetalert error.

Comment: You can check the 2 links above [php Contact Page](http://cavenpi.000webhostapp.com/contacto.php) & [html Contact Page](http://cavenpi.000webhostapp.com/contacto.html) in the update I left so you can have a better look of the results.

Comment: I updated both code snippets again. We still missed the actual test of the email. See the line `regx.test(...)`. Now we actual test if the email has the right format.

Comment: Also I tried to used await to wait for the SweetAlertSuccess() promise to resolve. The SweetAlert documentation hints that it acutally returns a promise, so this code should work. Have a try!

Comment: Hello Andre! Sorry for the delayed answer. I just tried the code out and it still does not show the error message when returning false. And for some reason the async/await isn't working (after seeing the code I thought too it would work since it makes sense to return a promise). Thanks for updating the ´regx.test´! You can check the updated [php Contact Page](http://cavenpi.000webhostapp.com/contacto.php)  to test how it's behaving currently. Thank you in advance for keeping up with me.

Comment: Ok, it seems that we have different errors here.  For debugging purposes, use `alert('error case')` and  `alert('success case')` instead of the SweetAlert Functions. Can you see the alert windows?

Comment: I also updated the code again. Play around with it, console.log how far you come in your code, remove the promise/await code and try without to come to the bottom of this issue ;)